# From where I can download SAP's SMP 3.0 development environment software?

Tags: sap-smp

I am new for SMP (SAP Mobile Platform), From where I can download SAP's SMP 3.0 development environment software ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download from this link but you'll need an S-user: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-49476

Answer (score 0):

The SDK location referred by Mikeal is not only relevant to start the development of mobile apps. You need a server as well. 
SAP provides SMP 3 on premise and cloud. The cloud version is called Hana cloud platform mobile services. SMP 3 (on-premise) is not available as a trial. But the cloud version is available for trial. 
You could find more information [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/mobility-platform/blog/2014/12/18/how-to-enable-hana-cloud-platform-mobile-services-trial) on the trial.

Also note that, the SMP SDK is common for on premise and cloud. Hence the app you are developing works on premise as well as trial without any code changes.